# how to avoid multiple http requests when same component is used twice

Tags: angular

How to avoid multiple http requests when same component is used twice in template

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8sgrgz

hello component is used twice in the template and its making calling service method for http data

```
  return this.http
    .get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
      q=London&appid=517c7bbf790248290ad52d57725c4d5f')
    .map((res) => {return res.json()})
                  .catch((error:any) => 
                       Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server 
     error')).share();} 

the http request should happen only once 
but its happening more than once
```

Comment: Don't get the data directly from http, add a singleton service and inject it in the component and use a BehaviorSubject to store the fetched data.

Comment: if you check in the stackblitz link mentioned I have already done it in a service

Comment: Yeah, but you have to cache your requests. I'll add the answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Behaviour subject to hold your data once you fetch it:

```
private data$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Add a function to get data:

```
  getData() {
    return this.data$.pipe(
      switchMap(data => {
        if (data) {
          return of(data); // If data was saved, just return it (you're actually returning an observable of data, because switchMap needs observables to switch for every other observable emission)
        } else {
          return this.http.get("") // If it wasn't, make a new http request
            .pipe(tap(newData => this.data$.next(newData))); // And save the data on the subject
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Hope that helps.